# Why does babel-node CLI seem to include all transformers?

Tags: babeljs

`babel-node` seems to include all transformers (haven't verified), including transformers that should have been optional.

I do not want that. I just want the default functionality. What I'm doing right now is `blacklist`ing the optional transforms I don't want.

What's up? Am I missing something here? Is the documentation on the website wrong or outdated?

Comment: Do you have an example? It shouldn't behave any differently from the normal compilation command.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will assume use of Babel 6 where es2015 is most commonly used preset, which for better or for worst does includes babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs.

I'll give you three ways to deal with this:

1. This one is the simplest just install babel-preset-es2015-native-modules and configure your .babelrc like this:

```html
{
  "presets": ["es2015-native-modules"], 
}
```

2. You can install babel-preset-es2015 and configure your .babelrc like this to disable the plugging:

```html
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "disablePlugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

3. Install all transforms minus modules-commonjs manually then configure your .babelrc like this:

```html
{
  plugins: [
            'transform-es2015-template-literals',
            'transform-es2015-literals',
            'transform-es2015-function-name',
            'transform-es2015-arrow-functions',
            'transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions',
            'transform-es2015-classes',
            'transform-es2015-object-super',
            'transform-es2015-shorthand-properties',
            'transform-es2015-computed-properties',
            'transform-es2015-for-of',
            'transform-es2015-sticky-regex',
            'transform-es2015-unicode-regex',
            'check-es2015-constants',
            'transform-es2015-spread',
            'transform-es2015-parameters',
            'transform-es2015-destructuring',
            'transform-es2015-block-scoping',
            'transform-es2015-typeof-symbol',
            ['transform-regenerator', { async: false, asyncGenerators: false }],
  ],
}
```